# Default Focus on AutoCompleteExtender textbox not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, autocompleteextender

I am using the AutoCompleteExtender on a webpage I am creating and noticed that after I set the defaultfocus on my form to the textbox that the AutoCompleteExtender is targetting it stopped working. I can click off of the textbox and then reselect it and the AutoCompleteExtender starts working. If I remove the defaultfocus it works every time. Is this a bug in the AutoCompleteExtender?

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by 
install the last version AjaxControlToolkit by (AjaxControlToolkit -Version 17.1.1) 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/AjaxControlToolkit/